# Issue in the structure of the ASP.NET MVC project retreiving error 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and using C# to create a project. The file structure looks like the image below. Now I am confused about the structure of the project. For each model, I have a controller and a view page please see below

[image].

I have two different models activity and activity log, an activity model in which user activities are added and an activity log which shows the relevant logs of activities related to the user. But now when I try to open the activity page, I get the following error. I think I am doing something wrong in the structure of the project.

[image]

The code for adding activity

[image: activity]

Comment: Have you customized the routing settings? Because it seems that you enter the wrong address in the browser [with default route setting]

Comment: Try this:"https://localhost:5001/ActivityLog/Creat"

Answer (score 0):

Your valid path is 'https://localhost:5001/ActivityLog/AddActivity/4' unless you are using routing.

See the error page what is 'TeenUser' as I can not see any such controller in your controller folder?